# How can we assume the first homology group of the complement is zero when constructing a Casson handle?

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups, 4-manifolds

I am currently working through Scorpan's *Wild World of 4-Manifolds* specifically the section on Casson Handles. On page 78, he says if $D$ is the core of the handle after $n$ stages we may assume $\pi_1(M\setminus D)$ is a perfect group. Why? Here $M$ is a smooth closed simply-connected 4-manifold.

Clearly this says $H_1(M\setminus D) = 0$ by the Hurewicz theorem, and thus every loop in the complement bounds a surface in the complement. If a loop is contractible in $M$ then the graph of its contraction homotopy function will be a disk in $M$ which we can perturb to be immersed. If that disk does not intersect the partial Casson Handle, $D$, then it will remain in the complement, $M\setminus D$, and we can contract the loop to a point along it. Thus every non-trivial element of $\pi_1(M\setminus D)$ must bound an immersed disk in $M$ which has non-null intersection with $D$. I don't understand how removing $D$ and therefore removing a portion of that immersed disk does not create any 1-homology. If we can perturb the immersed disk so it does not intersect $D$ then we can contract along it and we get a trivial element of $\pi_1(M\setminus D)$, but if we can't perturb it off $D$ then we can shrink the loop down to the boundary of the intersection where it no longer bounds a surface in $M\setminus D$ and must therefore contribute to $H_1(M\setminus D)$. This would indicate either $\pi_1(M\setminus D) = 0$ or $H_1(M\setminus D) \ne 0$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Alexander duality does the job.

Comment: Doesn't that only work if M is a 4-sphere or if we can move the Casson handle into an embedded 4-sphere? The statement of Alexander duality in Hatcher seems to only apply to spheres. How do I generalize it?

Comment: $D$ embeds inside a 4-ball in $M$. One can though explicitly work out how to resolve these intersections between such an immersed disk an the handle. Introduce new intersections through finger moves (see the Freedman-Quinn book) and then when the intersection points are algebraically cancelling you can attach 1-handles along the arcs between a cancelling pair of intersection points.

Comment: So I isolate $D$ in an embedded 4-ball in $M$. Each whitney loop gives an immersed disk in the 4-ball. What you're saying is I can perturb the disks to intersect $D$ transversely and do finger moves of the kind on pg 19 of Freedman-Quinn to trade each intersection point of $D$ with the immersed disk for a pair of self intersection points in $D$. Next I perform surgery like the picture on pg 32 to get a capped grope for $D$ with one self intersection, and the immersed disk disjoint from $D$. I use more gropes to push the cap's intersection point to infinity and continue Scorpan's program?